# Windows Phone 8 app translation

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, translation

I am trying to develop a mobile application on Windows Mobile 8 in Hindi language. More precisely, I have an application in that only supports the English language and would like to add Hindi language support to it. The application can be found [here](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/ApplicationDetails?ProductId=48c664c4-72bc-4abe-8780-d86861d332dc) on the Windows store.

I am interested in building it in Hindi in the same codebase. Any ideas on how to add Hindi language in the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed information to help you translate your app on Microsoft's [How to build a localized app for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx) page. Here's the most important part for what you want, but I advise reading the whole thing:

> To add additional languages
>
> 1. After you have created and tested your app using a neutral language, you can add supported languages.
>      On the project’s Properties page, in the Supported Culture box, select the language(s) you would like your app to support.
> 2. Save the project.
>
>    - Note:
>        Visual Studio has created a new resource file for each supported language that is a copy of the neutral resource file (AppResources.resx) and renamed it to include the locale code that reflects the new resource file’s Culture.
> 3. Replace the neutral language values in each supported language resource file with translated values.
>
>    - Caution:
>        To insure that the correct description of the localized languages for your app will be seen by users in the Windows Phone Store, use the following practices: If you need to remove a Supported Culture that you have added (by clearing the selection in the list in Project Properties) be sure to remove the associated Supported Language in WMAppManifest.xml (using the list in Manifest Designer > Supported Language > Packaging). Also, ensure that you understand the impact before modifying the Supported Languages list or Default Language in WMAppManifest.xml.

Hindi is one of the supported languages. If you need to check to see if any given language is supported, you can do so at the [Windows Phone 8 Feature and service availability](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/feature-and-service-availability) page. This currently includes:

> Albanian, Arabic, Azerbaijani, Basque (Basque), Belarusian, Bosnian (Latin), Bulgarian, Catalan, Chinese (Simplified and Traditional), Croatian, Czech, Danish, Dutch, English (UK and US), Estonian, Filipino, Finnish, French, Galician, German, Greek, Hausa, Hebrew, Hindi, Hungarian, Igbo, Indonesian, Italian, Japanese, Kazakh, Korean, Latvian, Lithuanian, Macedonian, Malay, Norwegian (Bokmål), Persian, Polish, Portuguese (Brazil and Portugal), Romanian, Russian, Serbian (Latin), Slovak, Slovenian, Spanish (Mexico and Spain), Swedish, Thai, Turkish, Ukrainian, Uzbek, Vietnamese, Yoruba.